# Does Weaviate support bulk query?

Tags: weaviate

Data is indexed against a class in weaviate, I have used vectorizer equals none while creating the class (As the app is providing embeddings). My query is, is there a way I can perform bulk query. Example: I need to search for 15 inputs, instead of looping over and querying 15 times, is there a way this can be done in one-shot?

Answer (score 0):

You can use batching: https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/current/restful-api-references/batch.html.

If you're using the Python client, see these docs: https://weaviate-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/weaviate.batch.html#weaviate.batch.Batch.

Comment: As the first line of the document link shared says 'With batch you can upload a lot of data objects in bulk', the batching is more specific to loading the data, my question is more about querying the data. Say, I want to query for a list of input at once, is that possible?
Please advise!

Comment: Querying in batch is currently not supported by the API or clients.